# What does IF_ICMPNE mean?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, jvm-bytecode

For the following Java class:

```
public class ArtClass {
   public boolean foo(int x) {
      if(x == 3956681)
        return true;
      else if(x == 9855021)
        return true;
      else if(x == 63085561)
          return true;
      else
        return false;
   }
}
```

Its JVM instructions are:

```
I4 Branch 1 IF_ICMPNE L3
I13 Branch 2 IF_ICMPNE L5
I22 Branch 3 IF_ICMPNE L7
```

I understand that the first branch is in the third line and the same for the second and third branches but what does `IF_ICMPNE` mean and also what do `I4`, `I13`, and `I22` mean?

Comment: This could be totally wrong, but I'm going to guess `IF_ICMPNE` means `If Integer Compare Not Equal`

Comment: I don't usually like "lmgtfy" answers/comments, but... did you try googling "IF_ICMPNE"? That gives me the answer right there. You _may_ need to search for something like "java IF_ICMPNE" if your google results are different than mine.

Comment: @yshavit It's also about the `I4`, `I13`, `I22`. I couldn't understand them.

Comment: @AdamAmin If that's the part you don't understand, you should edit the question (body and title) to reflect it. As written, the primary question is about IF_ICMPNE. As to those `I`s, I _suspect_ (but am not sure) that they're just telling you the byte offset within the instruction set. "This is instruction at byte 4, at byte 13," etc. You should also post what tool you're using to look at these, since javap, for instance, has slightly different format.

Comment: @yshavit jokes on you, first thing that comes up now when you google "if_icmpne" is this page lol

Comment: @chris I became the very thing I was trying to defeat!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the output, `javap -c` produced for your class (`javap` is a tool that ships with each standard JDK):

```
Compiled from "ArtClass.java"
public class ArtClass {
  public ArtClass();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public boolean foo(int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: ldc           #2                  // int 3956681
       3: if_icmpne     8
       6: iconst_1
       7: ireturn
       8: iload_1
       9: ldc           #3                  // int 9855021
      11: if_icmpne     16
      14: iconst_1
      15: ireturn
      16: iload_1
      17: ldc           #4                  // int 63085561
      19: if_icmpne     24
      22: iconst_1
      23: ireturn
      24: iconst_0
      25: ireturn
}
```

The meaning of all instructions has been specified in the [“Instruction Set” chapter of the The Java® Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-6.html). The instruction [if_icmpne](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.if_icmp_cond) will pop two **i**nt values, **c**o**mp**are them, and branch to the specified target **if** **n**ot **e**qual.

The output of `javap` makes it pretty clear, which targets have been specified by the branch instructions, as they match the numbers printed before each instruction.

If you use a different tool producing different output, you have to refer to the tool’s documentation regarding, how to decipher the output. Comparing with `javap`’s output suggests that these prefixes like `I4` also refer to bytecode offsets, but without further context, e.g. seeing the other instructions of the method, that’s quiet meaningless.

Comment: Hi Holger, "and branch to the specified target if not equal." by branch means a "jump" ? Like goto sentence? Thanks

Comment: @DiegoRamos yes, branch means “continue execution at the specified location”, just like goto is a(n unconditional) branch instruction.

Answer (score 2):

here a doc: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/kwxm/JVM/if_icmpne.html

**if_icmpne**:

> ```
> Description: 
>
> jump to label if the two integer refs are not equal
> ```